# What are the criteria for making a function a member vs. a friend?

Tags: c++, member, friend

When I can decide whether a particular function/operator should be declared as a friend function/operator for a class or a member function/operator of a class.?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to access the "guts" of your class (i.e. the private members) by a function that is not really related to your class. A typical example is the

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& foo)
```

which you overload so that you can simply display your object via the iostreams, like

```
std::cout << my_object;
```

In this case, assuming you need to grant access to your class private members, the function should be `friend`. It cannot even be a member function, since in that case you should call it like

```
my_object << (std::cout);
```

which looks, well, quite odd.